# Can anyone explain to me how additional post params are added on this website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, post, web

I'm currently investigating methods to prevent automated log in to the website.

Here's a website which puzzles me: http://linklicious.me/

The log in form looks normal and has 2 fields - emailAddress and password.

However, each time I post with it, 2 additional params **x=49&y=17** are added to the post request:

```
emailAddress=oueaoeu&password=acdd3e5e93oeuaoeu&x=49&y=17
```

this happens even when I disable scripts on the website with NoScript.

That's a nice trick I'd love to use on my own website. But how this is done really puzzles me.

Can anyone explain to me, how this is done?

Comment: They're added by browsers when you click on an image map and certain input types - they're the x/y coordinates of the click's location on whatever you'd clicked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using an image to submit the form. It is part of the HTML standard and does not require javascript or anything else.

```
<input type="image" class="fLeft loginbtn" src="/Content/Images/Home/Login2.png" alt="Login">
```

The `x` and `y` you are seeing are actually the coordinates where you clicked the "Login" image.

> [`<input type="image">`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/image) ... an image from which a user can select a coordinate and submit the form ...

More specifically, from the [HTML4 specification for input control types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#input-control-types):

> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of the image. The submitted data includes name.x=x-value and name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the name attribute, and x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.

It is (usually) not used to prevent automated logins, but I guess that a very simple web bot might not "click" on the image and send coordinates that way.

If no coordinates were received it could for example mean that

- it is a bot that doesn't send coordinates.
- it is a user without a "pointing device" (mouse, touch screen).
- it is a user that did not use any available pointing device (but the keyboard perhaps).
- it is a bad browser that didn't follow the standard.

If coordinates were received it could for example mean that

- it is a bot that recognizes `<input type="image" />`.
- it is a human who clicked the image.
- it is a human who used the keyboard to submit the form (probably via the image), but their browser decided to send coordinates anyways.

So basically, it is not a security measure of any sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use image button (`<input type="image" ...`) to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

It's sending an exact coordinates (X, Y) on image you've just clicked to the server. Submit button is an image

```
<input type="image" class="fLeft loginbtn" src="/Content/Images/Home/Login2.png" alt="Login">
```